# NGX-Quill not getting any content on submit

Tags: javascript, angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am using "ngx-quill": "^14.3.0" with "@angular/core": "~12.2.0".

Its registered in the app module:
QuillModule (not for root)

And in the lazy loaded module:
QuillModule (not for root)

```css
  public editor = {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image'],
    ],
  };


this.caseFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      description: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
)}
```

```html
   <quill-editor 
            #descriptionEditor
            formControlName="description"
            name="description"
            placeholder="Enter Text"
            [modules]="editor"
            format="text"
        >
        </quill-editor>
```

When I submit the form the description field is empty.

I have tried also using ngModel and onContentChanged without reactive form and I dont get any response.

Also the editor seems unresponsive.
When I enter text its written on top of the placeholder and the placeholder is not removed.

Open to ideas.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the process serving the angular application. And everything worked fine. Still a mystery why this happened in the first place